# Creating an animation in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, macos, graphics

I have around 100 PNGs (that I created) that I want to create an animation out of. I however created the animation in a vector graphics editor, therefore each PNG has a white background. How do I make Xcode not show the white background and instead just the image itself? I will be displaying the animation in a transparent window, so a background completely ruins the effect.

Note I'm using Xcode 3.2.6 on Snow Leopard. I'm specifically asking about a Mac application *not* an iOS one.

Comment: Are you trying to create an Xcode plugin or something? What does your IDE have to do with things?

Comment: My application has nothing to do with Xcode. The reason I mention Xcode is because I am developing my app *in* Xcode and considering Xcode has a unique Cocoa interface, it's an important part of the soution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend exporting your images again with a transparent background. That would save you a lot of trouble. If that's not an option, have a look at [Quartz 2D Masks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html).